# How to insert JSON OBJECT data into SQLite

Tags: json, sqlite

I have the following code to insert JSON object into SQLITE database.
I used for loop to insert each json object data into the database.
But the last JSON object is only inserted into the database.

```
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE  news_posts (id integer primary key, title text, content text,thumbnail text,url text,date datetime)');
 });  
 for (var i = 0; i < json.posts.length; i++) {
      db = window.openDatabase("news", "1.0", "Posts database", 200000);
      db.transaction(function(tx) {
       tx.executeSql("INSERT  INTO news_posts   (title,content,thumbnail,url,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", [json.posts[i].title,json.posts[i].content,json.posts[i].thumbnail,json.posts[i].url,json.posts[i].date], function(tx, res) {
           console.log("Success");
       });
    });
 }
```

Comment: How many "Success" messages do you see in the console?

Comment: 68(json response size) logs @Googie

Comment: How was the `news_posts` table created? Could you please paste the `CREATE TABLE` statement for it? (you can get it by with `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'news_posts';`)

Comment: I updated the post with that code. @Googie

Comment: You should provide also an error handler function (not just result handler), because having call to result handler does not mean that it succeeded. Add one more handler function to your query, which will print errors for you. Then see if you have errors, or not.

Comment: @Googie I tried with error function. I don't have any errors. The statement executed successfully but its only insert last data of JSON Object into every rows.

Comment: Could you share with everybody what was the cause, so maybe someone else will benefint from it in future too?