# How to Insert json object into sqlite in react native?

Tags: json, react-native, sqlite

[How to store json object in react native sqlite storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861538/how-to-store-json-object-in-react-native-sqlite-storage/54862991#54862991)

[How to insert JSON OBJECT data into SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230979/how-to-insert-json-object-data-into-sqlite#comment48568573_30230979)

Hello, I'm using react-native-sqlite-storage library, and i need to insert a json object into a table, and i have no idea how to approach the matter given that i have checked previous posts,
please help.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer to my own question, it was just a matter of using right import which was a hell to find(import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-2') , but thankfully i found it with the help of the following links:
Hopefully this would help someone else.

https://npmmirror.com/package/react-native-sqlite-2/v/1.0.0
https://github.com/appasaheb4/Tutorial_JsonData-into-insert-sqlitedb-ios-android-reactNative

```
enter code here

import React from 'react';

import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-2'

const Colors = [
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow",
        value: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]


const App = () => {


const db = SQLite.openDatabase('test.db', '1.0', '', 1)
db.transaction(function(txn) {
  txn.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users', [])
  txn.executeSql(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(color_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, colors VARCHAR(30), Value VARCHAR(25))',
    []
  )
  for (var i = 0; i < Colors.length; i++) {
    const array = Colors[i];

    txn.executeSql('INSERT INTO Users (Value, colors) VALUES (?,?)', 
  [array.value,array.color])
  txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM `users`', [], function(tx, res) {
    for (let i = 0; i < res.rows.length; ++i) {
      console.log('item:', res.rows.item(i))
    }
  })
}
})
return(null)
}
export default App;
```